# Mysql convert minute to day hour min

Tags: mysql

I want a query where it takes minute and convert to day hour minute in mysql .
I saw few sites but dont find usefull .
Time1 consists of time in minutes but i need it to show in day hr min .

```
Mysql query is as follows.
"SELECT raf, family ,time1 from table ";
Ex : 1226 where i need to convert to x days y hrs and z min.
```

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: do you mean time1 is a unix timestamp - something like 1412661978? If so, check out the from_unixtime MySQL function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: please let us know the sample output you want when you have `1226` minutes as input

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code as a reference:

```
select 
concat(FLOOR(min/1440), " day(s) ", 
FLOOR((min%1440)/60), " hour(s) ", 
FLOOR(min%60), " minute(s) ") 
from time_test;
```

You will get the following results :

```
    min     calculated_value
    1440    1 day(s) 0 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 
    1220    0 day(s) 20 hour(s) 20 minute(s) 
    1330    0 day(s) 22 hour(s) 10 minute(s) 
    1900    1 day(s) 7 hour(s) 40 minute(s) 
    1500    1 day(s) 1 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 
    1700    1 day(s) 4 hour(s) 20 minute(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

All that is required is some simple integer division and remainder operations to derive days, hours and minutes from an integer number of minutes.

```
SELECT t.time1 DIV 1440            AS days 
     , (t.time1 MOD 1440 ) DIV 60  AS hours
     , (t.time1 MOD 1440 ) MOD 60  AS minutes 
  FROM (SELECT 1226 AS time1) t
```