# Convert microsecond timestamp into day hour minute for google cluster traces in mysql

Tags: mysql, dataset, unix-timestamp, epoch

I want to:
GOAL: to check how many tasks occur in which machines during its available duration for 1 month (30 days)
I tried [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229502/mysql-convert-minute-to-day-hour-min) and [here2](http://DECLARE%20@UTC%20BIGINT%20SET%20@UTC%20=%201348203320997%20SELECT%20DATEADD(MILLISECOND,%20@UTC%20%25%201000,%20DATEADD(SECOND,%20@UTC%20/%201000,%20%2719700101%27))) and [here3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757811/converting-milliseconds-to-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds) but didn't work or I couldn't understand them well

I have two datasets that I combined together into one database called
"ftacpu" with two tables for my research that calculates how many tasks occur in which machine while it is up and running for 30 days or more:

a) Event_trace: which has a list of PC machines (700 machines) that are available randomly for a certain duration of the day (start time and end time) for 6 months starting from 22 January 2007 (Unix time Epoch),

and

b) Task_events: which has a list of different tasks aka google trace (around 200k tasks) that occur in a certain time of the day randomly ( in microseconds) for 30 days and allocated on those pc machines.

QUESTION is:

Since event_trace table time on Unix time and it is straight forward to convert aka (extract(the day from FROM_UNIXTIME()), yet I am struggling with task_events table time that I want to convert microsecond time of task_events table into day  hour minute so I could compare easily:

How many tasks occur by a certain machine during that day for day1, day2, ...., dayn

THE SAMPLE of the MYSQL query:

```
Select e.machine_id, task_index, extract(day from FROM_UNIXTIME(t.event_start_time)) 'Machine_Start_day', extract(hour from FROM_UNIXTIME(t.event_start_time)) + extract(minute from FROM_UNIXTIME(t.event_start_time)) / 60 'Machine_Start_H:M', extract(day from FROM_UNIXTIME(t.event_end_time)) 'Machine_End_day', extract(hour from FROM_UNIXTIME(t.event_end_time)) + extract(minute from FROM_UNIXTIME(t.event_end_time)) / 60 'Machine_End_H:M', e.time ('22/01/2007') 
From ftacpu.event_trace t JOIN ftacpu.task_events e 
ON e.machine_id = t.node_id 
Where  e.time >= 'Machine_Start_H:M' and e.time <= 'Machine_End_H:M' 
Order by 'Machine_Start_day' asc;
```

output sample

```
  machine_id task_index  Machine_Start_day  Machine_End_day Machine_Start_H:M Machine_End_H:M   e.time(micosecond) 
  
    `5`,       '1043',      '21',           '21',       '22.3333',   '22.6500',    '1076390000000'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: I just added output